# C++ - Use ofstream to create file in a different directory?

Tags: c++, ofstream

Let's say I want to create a file and my project folder is located inside a folder on my Desktop.  How would I create a file using ofstream onto my desktop?

Comment: The answer is in your question; use a `std::ofstream`. There is no magic voodoo in the logic that is somehow different for `std::ofstream` than for any other file-creation mechanism. You need a valid path to the folder and permissions to write to it; just like any other mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your question could be reformulated as **"How do I get the Desktop Path in a operating system?"**.

Once you have it, just join it with your filename and then use ofstream. No secrets!

```
ofstream file;
file.open( YOUR_FULL_PATH_HERE, ios::binary ); // suppose here you want binary!
// write your stuff here...
file.close();
```

The way you obtain the Desktop path depends on the operating system. In Windows, for example, you can use `SHGetSpecialFolderPath( CSIDL_DESKTOP )`, but in a Linux or Mac OS X, you gotta check how it's done (probably `getenv( "HOME" )` will be enough for you to get the Desktop from the home directory for these "UNIX-based" cases).

Comment: Why `ios::binary`? OP hasn't provided any details about what he wants to write to this file.

Comment: it was just an example... I will edit here...

Comment: @LihO: Exactly. So why not?

Comment: @WagnerPatriota: I find it kinda funny that you rephrased his question to "How do I get the Desktop Path..." and in first sentence of answer you say "once you have it..." :D btw I'm the one who upvoted it

Comment: One seems to be a student. When we are learning, sometimes we don't know even how to formulate the question. This one looks very simple, but he/she is still learning.